# Знаки препинания при однородных членах предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить знаки препинания в следующем предложении:

*Экономические термины инфляция, валюта, эмиссия известны широкому кругу читателей.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант 1:

***Экономические термины: инфляция, валюта, эмиссия — известны широкому кругу читателей.*** (Перед перечислением делается пауза.)

> 8. Если однородные члены предложения, стоящие после обобщающего слова, не заканчивают собой предложения, то перед ними ставится **двоеточие**, а после — **тире**: *Разве все эти вещи: **карандаш** в оправе, записная **книжка**, **часы**, фотографический **аппарат** — не говорят больше всяких слов об интересном госте?* (Пришв.)

Вариант 2:

***Экономические термины «инфляция», «валюта», «эмиссия» известны широкому кругу читателей.*** (После слова "термины" нет выраженной паузы.)

Сравнить: *Романы Гончарова «Обломов», «Обрыв», «Обыкновенная история» образуют своего рода трилогию*.

Источник: Справочник Розенталя ([**§ 15. Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103)).